# Set product name per store view programmatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, store-view

How can I set the name of a product in a specific language (store view)?

Comment: Have you tried setting `$product->setStoreId($anotherStoreId);` before saving?

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that in a couple of days. But I can tell you now: it feels weird because it's not part of [ProductInterface](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Api/Data/ProductInterface.php).

Comment: no reply? how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code, to create custom script in root, than add below code in script :

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$product = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

$product
    ->setName('demo name ')
    ->setSku('sku-name')
    ->setPrice(0.00)
    ->setStatus(2)// Disabled
    ->setWebsiteIds([1, 2])
    ->setVisibility(4)
    ->setAttributeSetId($product->getDefaultAttributeSetId())
    ->setTypeId('simple')
    ->save();

echo "Saved product ID " . $product->getId() . "\n";
```

**please check its work for me...**

Comment: It will save the same value for all store view.